# Battery issues with background scans

Tags: android, altbeacon

I'm using altbeacon's Android Beacon Library to do a background proximity scan to show the user a notification when they enter the range of 1 of my beacons when the app is in the background. I have made it work by adding this to my application file's `onCreate` method:

```
region = new Region("com.myapplication.identifier", 
                    Identifier.parse(Constants.beaconUUID), null, null); 
regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);
beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1000l);
beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(30000l);
```

I have code in the `didEnterRegion` method to range that beacon and display the notification for that location. I found 30 seconds the be the minimum acceptable frequency to still get the notifications when walking through the beacon range. I have noticed since I added this code that it is causing android 7.0 to report battery issues "between 1% and 2% battery usage per hour" even when I am not near any beacons. I have done a lot of iterations on different scan frequencies and have isolated the problem to be entirely independent of what actually is in `didEnterRegion`, and I'm pulling my hair out at this point. Anyone know a way to reduce the battery drain and still trigger `didEnterRegion`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duty cycle you mention of scanning for 1 second every 30 seconds is going to use a lot of battery:

```
beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1000l);
beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(30000l);
```

The library default is to scan for 10 seconds every 5 minutes (30000 seconds) in the background.  While both represent the same duty cycle of 1/30, starting and stopping scanning 10x more often uses significantly more energy. **I would revert the scan settings to the defaults, or even lengthen the background scan period if you can to save more battery.**

Understand that on Android 5+ that the app will continue to do a filtered low power scan even when in the between scan period, provided no beacons are around.  So you'll still get a callback if a beacon is detected within 5 seconds.

The only reason to do a periodic full power scan in the background is (a) for Android 4.x devices (b) for devices that don't have bluetooth chips supporting low power filtered scans or devices where all the hardware filters are in use and (c) the case where beacons are known to be around, so filtered background scans cannot continue.

Also, the point made by @sunnySydeUp in his answer is correct.  **You do need to be using the BackgroundPowerSaver** if you are not already, as this is what will switch your app automatically between foreground and background scan periods.  If you don't use this, you'll be scanning at the foreground rates all the time.

Comment: so if I do something like:   
            `beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1000l);
            beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(30000l);
            backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this); `I will still get notifications when walking through a range when the app is in the background?

Comment: Correct.  But again with that scan cycle you may drain battery faster than with the defaults.

Answer (score 1):

You can save some battery by keeping an instance of `BackgroundPowerSaver` in your `Application`.

```
import org.altbeacon.beacon.powersave.BackgroundPowerSaver;

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
    }
}
```

Source:
[Altbeacon Battery Manager](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/battery_manager.html)

Comment: Unfortunately that reduces the scan rate from 30 secs where I need it to 5 minutes. This function seems to be for apps where the scanning is predominantly when the app is in the foreground, whereas I'm actually stopping the scanning when the app is in the foreground and only scans in the background.